# NUMA enabled but can't detect node

Tags: centos, intel, centos6.4, numa

I have a Centos 6.4 (kernel 2.6.32) machine with 2x Intel X5670 (Westmere) in a SuperMicro X8DTG-D motherboard with 2.0a BIOS version. BIOS Settings for ACPI are:

ACPI Aware O/S: Enabled

APCI Version Features: APCI v3.0

NUMA Support: Enabled

ACPI SLIT Table: Enabled

When I run 'numactl --hardware' i see the following (Please forgive retyping):

> Available 2 nodes (0-1)
>
> node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 12 13 14 15 16 17
>
> node 0 size 12279 MB
>
> node 0 free 11555 MB
>
> node 1 cpus: 6 7 8 9 10 11 18 19 20 21 22 23
>
> node 1 size 12288 MB
>
> node 1 free 11804 MB
>
> node distances:
>
> node 0 1
>
> 0:   10 21
>
> 1:   21 10

I can see under /sys/devices/system/node/ that there are two nodes, which agrees with numactl. However whenever I attempt to find the numa node for a device i get -1, such as:

> cat /sys/class/net/eth0/device/numa_node
>
> -1

I get the same result regardless of which device I try under /sys/devices/pci0000:00/. I've researched all around, but can't find any indication as to what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding? Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks very much,

Phil